# onsen ons-toolbar on cordova

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, onsen-ui

I'm new in cordova development. 
I'm using Onsen UI (1.2.1) as layout framework.
I have a problem with title on ons-toolbar.

```
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">someTextHere</div>
</ons-toolbar>
```

If I run my program on ripple, the toolbar text rendered correctly (centered text), but in android emulator, it didn't (text align changed to left).

It happens only for text with 'center' class. Back button and menu button which also put in toolbar section, rendered perfectly on both simulator tools.

How can i fix it?

Thank your for helping me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to add the attribute `fixed-style`

```html
<ons-toolbar fixed-style>
    <div class="center">someTextHere</div>
</ons-toolbar>
```

Comment: woops...i didn't see it in onsen documentation. Thanks mate :)